# Matlab, high quality plot, two legends

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to produce a plot with two y-axis and two legends, looking something like this: [image]

I have modified a code I found online to produce a high-quality plot to use in reports/papers. I was wondering how you add a second y-axis in such a code? I have attached the matrix and code to produce the high-quality plot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aKZLFeoO1wmQ1P2tEiiucvOFI7PehkGL/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aKZLFeoO1wmQ1P2tEiiucvOFI7PehkGL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It appears that you're looking for 2 vertical axes and not 2 legends.  Your example contains 0 legends.  This confusion is likely why you did not find your solution in the matlab documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This is basically a comment, however, it grew too long, and I felt it was too important not to mention properly.

Reporting plots from Matlab should always, unless you have some *very* good excuse, be done using vector graphics, i.e. pdf, ps, eps or similar format. The reason for this is the quality, e.g. here I have taken your *high-quality* and the similar pdf-version and zoomed in.

[image: high-quality]

The png version has artifacts. The reason for this is that the png (similar for jpg and more) is that the picture is saved using pixels, thus when you zoom the quality deteriorate.

[image: pdf]

The pdf version, which is made with vector graphics, save the vectors, thus when I zoom the pdf viewer can regenerate the pixels and maintain the same quality. As an added bonus, the vector-graphic version is typically smaller in size.

This is made in Matlab using

```
saveas(gcf,'myfigure.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [yyaxis](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html) to add another plot with an axis. Take a look at the following modified portion of your code.

```
yyaxis left
plot(N(:,1),N(:,3)/(27.5*2),'b-','DisplayName','Location','LineWidth',lw); %<- Specify plot properites
yyaxis right
plot(N(:,1),N(:,4)/(27.5*2),'r-', 'DisplayName','NorthEast','LineWidth',lw); %<- Specify plot properites
legend('Location', 'NorthEast');
```